# Evaluating $\int_{|z-\pi |=\pi}^{}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^{2}-\pi^{2}}dz$

Tags: integration

> I have to solve the following Cauchy's integral
>
> $$\int_{|z-\pi |=\pi}^{}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z^{2}-\pi^{2}}dz$$

$$\begin{align}
|x+iy-\pi|=\pi 
&\quad\Rightarrow\quad |(x-\pi)+iy|=\pi \\[4pt]
&\quad\Rightarrow\quad \sqrt{(x-\pi)^{2}+iy^{2}}=\pi \\[4pt]
&\quad\Rightarrow\quad (x-\pi)^{2}+iy^{2}=\pi^{2}
\end{align}$$
On the other hand,
$$(z^{2}-\pi^{2})=(z-\pi)(z+\pi) \quad\Rightarrow\quad (z-\pi)(z+\pi)=0\; \text{if}\; z=\pi \;\text{or}\; z=-\pi$$
The problem is when putting it in the formula $\oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})}= 2\pi if(z_{0})$, because I have $2z_{0}$.

Comment: Is the 3 in the first line an engineering joke?

Comment: Hahahahaha idk what happened

Answer (score 1):

The singularity at $z=\pi$ is removable (through an easy application of L’Hopital) and therefore you will get zero for the integral.